# Recover hidden pictures from my system

Tags: data-recovery, file-system, images, hidden, gallery-vault

I am currently using [Calculator Vault](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.calculator.vault&hl=en) to hide my photos and would like to recover all my photos. But my system does not want to start since this morning. I have the password with which I lock it.

Where can I found all my pictures by the file manager ?

Thanks by advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

From the Google play page of the app-

> Q - I uninstalled this app and again installed. Can I get my locked
>   pictures back? A - You need to unlock pictures before uninstall. Files
>   are not available in new install.

Unless you can get the phone working to access the app again you won't be able to decrypt the files. Decryption won't be possible on your computer too.

Comment: Ok but so How the app can do that ? All encrypted files must be decryptable, no ?

Comment: The app itself doesn't have its source code published anywhere so it's hard to say what protocol it uses for encryption.

Comment: Do you think if I decompile the app, can I invert the protocol to retrieve my files ?

Comment: Unlikely. It's not easy to decrypt encrypted stuff without the key.